# ice:repeat inputText with List<String>, if String is immutable?

Tags: jsf, immutability, icefaces, textinput, repeat

I want `list` to be `List<String>`. First I display one `inputText`, each time a user enters data in the `inputText` I add another empty `inputText`. If the list already has some values I display them all + one empty one. 
But it doesn't work, because **Strings are immutable**.
 I made a **wrapper** for String as an workaround, but I don't like it. 
How could I make the `inputText` refer to the position in the backed list ?

```
<ice:repeat value="#{mBean.list}" var="xxx" valueChangeListener="{mBean.vcl}">
    <ice:inputText partialSubmit="true" value="#{xxx}" />
</ice:repeat>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't do IceFaces, but if the `<ice:repeat>` supports a `varStatus` attribute like as JSTL's `<c:forEach>` and Facelets' `<ui:repeat>`, then you can submit to a `List<String>` when accessing the individual item by list index instead of by `var` attribute as the following Facelet example:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.strings}" varStatus="loop">
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.strings[loop.index]}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

This way the value is set by the setter of the list, the [`List#set(index, value)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29) method.

Other than that, your best bet is really to wrap the String in a bean. I'm however pretty positive that JSTL `<c:forEach>` should also work out for you the above way, as long as you don't have it nested in another JSF repeating tag. You'll only miss that `valueChangeListener` attribute/feature you had in `<ice:repeat>`.

Comment: It works, thanks. For the new empty inputText I add an empty string to the list.

Comment: I'm back to this question. How about if you have a Set instead of List, you don't have an index in sets. As an workaround I transformed the set into a list ..

Comment: Support for `Set` in `DataModel` interface is planned in JSF 2.2. Else your best bet is homegrow a custom `DataModel` implementation similar to `ListDataModel` (hard part is to figure the index efficiently!)